# Why aren't my command bindings firing?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have defined a number of custom commands in my WPF application:

```
public class MyCommands {

    public static RoutedUICommand CopyPlateCommand;

    public static RoutedUICommand PreviousRecordCommand;

    public static RoutedUICommand NextRecordCommand;

    public static RoutedUICommand SearchCommand;

    public static RoutedUICommand SearchPlateCommand;

}
```

I have a `UserControl` which has `ContextMenus` that use some of these commands:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.UserControl1" 
        . . . > 
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <MenuItem Header="Copy Plate"   Command="{Binding cs:MyCommands.CopyPlateCommand}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Search Plate" Command="{Binding cs:MyCommands.SearchPlateCommand}" />
        </ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="TextBoxMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <MenuItem Header="Copy"            Command="{Binding Copy}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Copy Plate"   Command="{Binding cs:MyCommands.CopyPlateCommand}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Search Plate" Command="{Binding cs:MyCommands.SearchPlateCommand}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </UserControl.Resources>
                             . . . 
</UserControl>
```

There are no command bindings in `UserControl1`.

I have another `UserControl` that includes an instance of the `UserControl1` in it.  It also has `CommandBindings` that include the commands included on the context menus in `UserControl1`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.UserControl2" 
        . . . > 
    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Copy"                                    CanExecute="CopyCommand_CanExecute"      Executed="CopyCommand_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="cs:MyCommands.CopyPlateCommand"   CanExecute="CopyPlateCommand_CanExecute" Executed="CopyPlateCommand_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="cs:MyCommands.SearchPlateCommand" CanExecute="CopyPlateCommand_CanExecute" Executed="SearchPlateCommand_Executed" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
                             . . . 
    <c:UserControl1 . . . />
```

I've placed breakpoints in the various handlers for the commands, but the breakpoints are never hit.  What have I done wrong?  Do I have to put the command bindings into `UserControl1`?

No, my program does not use MVVM.  I started the project before I ever heard of MVVM.  I intend to convert this to MVVM at some point in the future, but I don't have time right now.  I need to get some bug fixes out the door and this is holding me up.

Thanks for understanding.

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the `RoutedUICommand` objects I created in my class were fields and not properites, that wasn't enough to get the program working.  I simply could not figure out how, in XAML, to set the `CommandTarget` property of the `MenuItems` in `UserControl1` to `UserControl2`.

I did get it working, but I ended up doing it in the code-behind.  What I did was I wrote a helper method called `FixMenuItems`:

```
private void FixMenuItems( FrameworkElement element, Func<MenuItem, bool> condition, FrameworkElement target ) {
    foreach ( MenuItem menuItem in element.ContextMenu.Items ) {
        if ( condition( menuItem ) ) {
            menuItem.CommandTarget = target;
        }
    }
}
```

I then wrote a public method called `SetupCommandTargets`:

```
public void SetupCommandTargets( FrameworkElement target, Func<MenuItem, bool> condition ) {
    FixMenuItems( Control1, condition, target );
    FixMenuItems( Control2, condition, target );        . . .
}
```

Then, in the constructors of `UserControl1` and `UserControl2`, I call the public function as necessary, as I moved the handlers for some of the controls into `UserControl1` because those handlers needed access private properties of that class.

I also had to remove the `Bindings` on the `Command` properties of the `MenuItems`.  I was able to do the `CommandBindings` in XAML.  It was just the `CommandTargets` I couldn't get to work.

After making all of these changes, everything works now.  The `MenuItems` all point to the right controls and they become enabled and disabled correctly.  They each perform their proper actions.  I'm happy.

Answer (score 3):

Your Command class needs to expose public properties, not public fields.

You have to bind to a property and not a field, because *most* binding is based on the
ComponentModel PropertyDescriptor model. Properties expose this this metadata that the binding engine needs to enable binding.

> **Binding to common language runtime (CLR) objects:**
>
> You can bind to public properties, sub-properties, as well as
> indexers, of any common language runtime (CLR) object. The binding
> engine uses CLR reflection to get the values of the properties.
> Alternatively, objects that implement ICustomTypeDescriptor or have a
> registered TypeDescriptionProvider also work with the binding engine.

Taken from the [binding source specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx).

**Example below:**

```
public class MyCommands {

    public static RoutedUICommand CopyPlateCommand { get; set; }

    public static RoutedUICommand PreviousRecordCommand { get; set; }

    public static RoutedUICommand NextRecordCommand { get; set; }

    public static RoutedUICommand SearchCommand { get; set; }

    public static RoutedUICommand SearchPlateCommand { get; set; }

}
```

When running the application in debug mode, check the "Output" window for binding errors.

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking at the output window and I did see binding errors.  I just couldn't figure out what the problem was.

Comment: If you feel this helped you with your problem, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: While you did point out a problem with my code, it wasn't the problem that kept everything from working.  Please see my answer to see what actually worked.  I have upvoted your answer, just the same.

Comment: It answers the question "Why aren't my command bindings firing." The answer you posted has nothing to do with why the commands didn't execute.

Comment: Even with the change you pointed out, the logic that was supposed to execute when the command binding fired didn't run.  The program didn't execute that logic until I made the changes in my answer.  So if my answer had nothing to do with why the bindings execute, why is it they only executed when I made those changes?